# How to delete blank spaces on a string column

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, replace, sql-server-2012

I have a `nvarchar(2000)` column which may store a long text as below

[image: blank rows after text]

There are a lot of blank rows at end of text. Is there a way to delete these blank rows (`char(10)`)?

Using `replace(column,char(10),'')` is not acceptable. I don't want to mess up the content above. How to delete these char(10) only at the end of text?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Can you paste the image as text

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)` with empty string:

```
declare @text nvarchar(max) = 
'first row
second row
third row



'
print '--Before--'
print @text
print '--End'

select @text = REPLACE(@text,CHAR(10)+CHAR(13),'')  --10 and 13, not 13 and 10!

print '--After'
print @text
print '--End'
```

Will give you:

```
--Before--
first row
second row
third row



--End
--After
first row
second row
third row
--End
```

In `Before` part there are 3 empty rows

**EDIT**

If each *empty* row got a space(s) then change chars in REPLACE statement and add RTRIM to cut off spaces left:

```
select @text = RTRIM(REPLACE(@text,CHAR(32)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),''))
```

Comment: Great logic switch! However, it will remove blank lines within the body of the text, not just the trailing

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes they will. If OP need that blank rows **inside** the body - he will not use this :)

Comment: It doesn't work on my side, don't know why.  Have you ever tried this in sqlserver?

Comment: @JoeGuan yes I have tested this, elseway there will be no output in my answer. What version of SQL Server do you use? And what error you get?

Comment: Please, add ACTUAL data from one of your rows, not a screenshot, there may be spaces in the empty rows and the solution might very.

Comment: I add solution to handle spaces in *empty* rows

Comment: My pleasure! :) if any of the answers were helpful feel free to accept/upvote them!

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @String nvarchar(2000) = 'Row 1 with some text
Row 2 with some other text



'


Select reverse(substring(Reverse(@String),patindex('%[0-z]%',Reverse(@String)),2000))+char(13)+char(10)
```

Returns

```
Row 1 with some text
Row 2 with some other text
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the sample data from gofr1. This method will ONLY delete the tailor lines. Tested, it works perfect in SSMS. :)

```
declare @text nvarchar(max) = 
'first row


second row
third row



'

print '--Before--'
print @text
print '--End'

--It will delete only the tailor lines.
set @text = reverse(stuff(reverse(@text),1,patindex('%'+char(13)+'[^'+char(10)+']%',reverse(@text)),''))  

print '--After'
print @text
print '--End'
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use RTRIM and LTRIM For your select query in SQL
For example

select RTRIM ( LTRIM ( '          j            '))  AS Column1

or If you want use trim on your web form.You can use databound event write string using Str.Trim();

Comment: TRIM doesn't work for char(10) and char(13), it only work for space

Comment: For SQL server Use the RTRIM and LTRIM to remove space.Or u can use the replace method.                          Another approach is u can cast char to string then apply the TRIM